# How do I write the following mathematical statement as a predicate logic formula?

Tags: predicate-logic

The mathematical statement that I has to write as a predicate logic formula in the language L = {<, =, f}, where f is unary function, is the following: "Strictly increasing function doesn't have a maximum."

I have an idea but I am not sure if it is correct:

$((\forall x)(\forall y)((x < y)\rightarrow (f(x) < f(y))))\rightarrow \neg(\exists x)(\forall y)(y < x)$

Comment: Proceed step-by-step; *strict increasing* will be : $\forall x,y \ (x < y \to f(x) < f(y))$.

Comment: I have added an idea. Is the idea correct?

Comment: $\cdots\to\neg\exists x\forall y[f(y)<f(x)\vee f(y)=f(x)]$.

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Comment: Quite correct; $¬(∃x)(∀y)(f(y) \le f(x))$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $\leq\notin L$. But acceptible as abbreviation I think.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written there is almost correct. A maximum conventionally uses $\leq$, not $<$. But more importantly, you aren't saying anything at all about $f$ in the second half. I think you want to say $(x\neq y\land f(x)\leq f(y))$ instead of just $(x< y)$

From an aesthetic standpoint, I would also prefer that $\lnot(\exists x)$ is swapped with $(\forall x)\lnot$. And then that the resulting $\lnot(\forall y)$ is swapped for $(\exists y)\lnot$ (although this does make the connection between the formula and the original goal of "does not have a maximum" a little more opaque). You have a bit more parentheses than you really need. So I would have written it as
$$
\forall x\forall y(x < y\rightarrow f(x) < f(y))\rightarrow\forall x\exists y(f(x)<f(y)
$$